# How can I change the x position of a div via javascript when I click on another div this way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, translate

```
<body>
  <div id = "SiteContainer">        
    <div id = "NavigationButtons"></div>    
    <div id = "ShowReelContainer">
      <div id= "NavigationBackward" name = "back" onclick="setPosition();">x</div>
      <div id= "NavigationForward" name = "forward" onclick="setPosition();">y</div>    
      <div id = "VideoWrapper"> 
        <div id = "SlideShowItem">
          <img src="Images/A.png" alt="A"></img>                    
        </div>
        <div id = "SlideShowItem">
          <img src="Images/B.png" alt="B"></img>                    
        </div>
        <div id = "SlideShowItem">
          <img src="Images/C.png" alt="C" ></img>                   
        </div>              
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <script>
    var wrapper = document.querySelector("#VideoWrapper");

    function setPosition(e) 
    {
      if(e.target.name = "forward")
      {
        if!(wrapper.style.left = "-200%")
        {
          wrapper.style.left = wrapper.style.left - 100%;
        }   
      }
      else 
      {
        if(e.target.name = "back")
        {
          if!(wrapper.style.left = "0%")
          {
            wrapper.style.left = wrapper.style.left + 100%;
          } 
        }
      } 
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Hi, I am very new to `javascript`. What I am trying to do, is change the `x-position` of a `div` when another `div` (`NavigationForward` or `NavigationBackward`) is clicked. However it does not appear to do anything at all. Basically if the `div` with name `forward` is clicked, I want to translate the `VideoWrapper` -`100%` from it's current `position` and +100% when "back". The `css` `div` itself `VideoWrapper` has a `width` of `300%`. Inside this `div` as you can see is a `SlideShowItem` which is what will change. Perhaps I am adding and subtracting 100% the wrong way?

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for helping me out with this...I had just one more query, I am trying to hide the arrows based on whether the wrapper is at the first slide or the last slide. If its on the first slide, then I'd hide the left arrow div and if it's on the last, I'd hide the right arrow, otherwise display both of em. Ive tried several ways to achieve this, but none of em work, so Ive resorted to using copies of variables from the function that works. Even then it does not work. It appears that my if and else if statements always evaluate to false, so perhaps I am not retrieving the position properly?

```
function HideArrows()
{
    var wrapper2 = document.getElementById("VideoWrapper");

    var offset_x2 = wrapper2.style.left;

    if(parseInt(offset_x2,10) == max_x)
    {
        document.getElementById("NavigationForward").display = 'none';
    }

    else if(parseInt(offset_x2,10) == min_x)
    {
        document.getElementById("NavigationBackward").display = 'none';
    }

    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("NavigationForward").display = 'inline-block';
        document.getElementById("NavigationBackward").display = 'inline-block';
    }
}
```

//html is the same except that I added a mouseover = "HideArrows();"

```
<div id = "ShowReelContainer" onmouseover="HideArrows();">
```

Comment: Try to make a jsfiddle so we can look at it.

Comment: can you post the code that is going to make it happen?

Comment: not sure if this solves any thing but this `if!(wrapper.style.left = "0%")` should be `if(wrapper.style.left = "0%")` --  without `!` after `if`

Comment: here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MvcyA/

Comment: All of your `if` statements will evaluate to true as you are assigning a value to those properties.  In your `if` statements change `=` to `==` and the one where you have `if!(` I think you are looking for `!=`.

Comment: Yes! I was looking for a "Not equals" boolean, I have made these changes in my code, but it still does not work.

Comment: There are numerous errors in your code. 1) The `id` of your html elements must be unique. 2) The boolean tests 3) `wrapper.style.left + 100%` is not correct syntax -- you will need to calculate the percentage value then perform addition or subtraction. Finally, open up your browser's debug console (usually F12) to quickly point out any syntax errors like these.

Comment: I am trying to add and subtract 100 %, I'll change the same ids to a class instead as I need to reuse "SlideShowItem".

Comment: `var pc_value = left * 1.00` is 100% of the left value which you use to add or subtract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this type o slider functionality your div `VideoWrapper` must have `overflow:hidden` style, and your `SlideShowItem`divs must have a `position:relative` style.

Then to move the slides forward or backward you can use the style `left` which allows you to move the divs `SlideShowItem` relative to it's parent `VideoWrapper`.

I've tested this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QfXhJ/) on JSFiddle.

It seems to work as you described in your question, although you may need to do some adjustments, like defining the width of your slides, how many they are and so on.

For the sake of simplicity, I defined them as "constants" on the top of the code, but I think you can work from that point on.

**CSS**

```
#VideoWrapper{
    position:relative; height:100px; white-space:nowrap;width:500px;
    margin-left:0px; border:1px solid #000; overflow:hidden;  }

.SlideShowItem{
    width:500px; height:100px;display:inline-block;position:relative; }

#NavigationForward, #NavigationBackward{
    cursor:pointer;float:left; background-color:silver;margin-right:5px; 
    margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; padding:10px; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id = "SiteContainer">  

    <div id = "NavigationButtons">
    </div>  

    <div id = "ShowReelContainer">

            <div id= "NavigationBackward" name = "back" onclick="setPosition('back');">prev</div>
            <div id= "NavigationForward" name = "forward" onclick="setPosition('forward');">next</div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>

        <div id = "VideoWrapper">

            <div class= "SlideShowItem" style="background-color:blue;">    
                Slide 1
            </div>

            <div class = "SlideShowItem" style="background-color:yellow;">
                Slide 2
            </div>

            <div class = "SlideShowItem" style="background-color:pink;">
                Slide 3
            </div>              

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var unit = 'px'; var margin = 4; var itemSize = 500 + margin; var itemCount = 3; var min_x = 0; var max_x = -(itemCount-1) * itemSize;

function setPosition(e)  {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("VideoWrapper");
    var slides = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var offset_x = slides[0].style.left.replace(unit, '');
    var curr_x = parseInt(offset_x.length == 0 ? 0 : offset_x);

    if(e == "forward")
    {
       if(curr_x <= max_x)
            return;

        for(var i=0; i<slides.length; i++)
            slides[i].style.left= (curr_x + -itemSize) + unit;
    }
    else if(e == "back")
    {
        if(curr_x >= min_x)
            return;

        for(var i=0; i<slides.length; i++)
            slides[i].style.left= (curr_x + itemSize) + unit;  
    } }
```

After you analyze and test the code, I don't really know what's your purpose with this, I mean, you maybe just playing around or trying to develop something for a personal project, but if you are looking for something more professional avoid to create things like sliders on your own, as there are tons of plugins like this available and well tested out there on the web.

Consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) with [NivoSlider](http://dev7studios.com/plugins/nivo-slider/), it works like a charm and is cross browser.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I also added the style transition: left .7s ease-in-out; under .SlideShowItem. The irksome aspect of which the transition doesn't work on the first "forward" click, but then after the first click all goes well. Both Forward and Backward functions. I even added this to your jsfiddle to test it out, and the same thing happens. If you add the "transition: left .7s ease-in-out;" to your jsfiddle, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: OK, I figured this out, I am just posting this for the benefit of everyone else. For anyone using such a setup, You need to add the style "left:" to the div inside the wrapper. e.g. "left:0;" This is for firefox and internet explorer, they require initial position values for css transitions to work properly.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using jQuery, this will reduce your coding by quite a bit. Can read more here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I've created a simple fiddle for you to take a look at. This example uses the .animate() method to reposition two div elements based on the CSS 'left' property.

CSS:

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    bottom: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#one, #two {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;    
}

#one {
    background: pink;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#two {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    left: 100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="one">Div One</div>
     <div id="two">Div Two</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
var one, two, container;
function animateSlides(){

    one.animate({
        left : '-100%'
    }, 1000, function(){
        one.animate({
            left : 0
        }, 1000);
    });

    two.animate({
        left : 0
    }, 1000, function(){
        two.animate({
            left:'100%'
        }, 1000);
    });

};

$(function(){
    one = $('#one');
    two = $('#two');
    container = $('#container');

    setInterval(animateSlides, 2000);
});
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/adamfullen/vSSK8/3/

Comment: it's funny that's the questions title specifically says javascript, and there's no jquery tag either...

Comment: This question is not about jQuery, it's about pure JavaScript, so your answer doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: Agreed, just offering an alternative approach as an educational note.

Comment: Thanks Adam for the alternative approach